# On a PBX (Asterisk) determine which phones are connected

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx

I am using Asterisk as my PBX. On my `sip.conf` I used to have this option enabled:

```
[general]
...
qualify=yes
```

more info about qualify can be found in [HERE](https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-sip-qualify/).

Thanks to that option I was able to tell if phones (peers) where connected or not. When I ran the command `sip show peers` on asterisk CLI I was able to see which phones where connected and which phones where disconnected (unreachable).

**For some reason the `qualify=yes` option was giving me a lot of problems.** Phones got disconnected and reconnected. Because of that reason several calls where lost. This lead me to have to place `qualify=no` on my sip.conf.

So now that I have disabled the qualify option I am trying to find a way to tell if the peers are reachable or not. **Perhaps there is a way to send a ping message to a peer?**. For example I can call a peer and if the phone rings I know the peer is connected. But how can I do this without having to place a phone call?

Please note that the PBX is in the cloud (public ip). The peers are inside a network. So I see the same public IP address for all the peers.

Comment: Might `qualify=60` or some larger number still do the job ?

Comment: What sip implementation are you using? `chan_sip` or `chan_pjsip`

Comment: `sip notify` is the way to "ping" a sip client but it sends a NOTIFY message instead of an ICMP ECHO. If you have set debugging high enough you can watch the reply come in.

Comment: @user3788685 chan_sip

Comment: I think the solution might be `sip notify` Going to give it a try @ssnobody. Thanks!